# Boot problem with grub; Arch Linux, Xen, DomU

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2, xen

**Inside my Dom0**

My error log:

```
sudo xl create /etc/xen/arkOS-Dev_PV.cfg

/var/log/xen/bootloader.1.log
   pyGRUB  version 0.6
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │ Arch GNU/Linux, with Linux core repo kernel                            │
 │                                                                        │
 │                                                                        │
 │                                                                        │
 │                                                                        │
 │                                                                        │
 │                                                                        │
 │                                                                        │
 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Use the ^ and ┴ keys to select which entry is highlighted.
Press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the
commands before booting, 'a' to modify the kernel arguments
before booting, or 'c' for a command line.







[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Error opening /boot/vmlinuz-linux in guest
```

My old setup:

/etc/xen/ArkOS-Dev.cfg.old

```
name = 'ArkOS-Dev'
kernel = "/mnt/arch/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/mnt/arch/boot/x86_64/archiso.img"
extra = "archisobasedir=arch archisolabel=ARCH_201511"
memory = 512
disk = [ "phy:/dev/sda3,xvda,w", "file:/home/xen/ISO/archlinux-2015.11.01-dual.iso,xvdb:cdrom,r" ]
vif = [ 'mac=00:16:3e:49:2b:a1,bridge=xenbr0' ]
```

My current setup:

/etc/xen/Arkos-Dev.cfg

```
name = 'ArkOS-Dev'
bootloader = "pygrub"
memory = 512
disk = [ "phy:/dev/sda3,xvda,w" ]
vif = [ 'mac=00:16:3e:49:2b:a1,bridge=xenbr0' ]
```

lsblk -f

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                      
|-sda1 vfat         FF2C-B8A3                            /boot
|-sda2 btrfs        b3f4f40f-a8a1-4438-a187-dc02f2104340 /
|-sda3                                                   
`-sda4 swap         f90e6e95-5f00-4138-aa76-13feb4bce985 [SWAP]
```

mount -o loop /home/xen/ISO/archlinux-201511.01-dual.iso /mnt
ls /mnt -lah

```
total 26K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.0K Nov  1 09:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  136 Oct 29 20:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.0K Nov  1 09:34 EFI
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.0K Nov  1 09:35 arch
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.0K Nov  1 09:34 isolinux
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.0K Nov  1 09:34 loader
```

mount /dev/sda3 /mnt

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda3,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

**Inside my DomU (via old setup)**

lsblk -f

http://pastebin.archlinux.fr/1717775

arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash
lsblk -f

http://pastebin.archlinux.fr/1717771

ls -lah /boot

http://pastebin.archlinux.fr/1717772

My grub file:

/boot/grub/grub.cfg

http://pastebin.archlinux.fr/1717774

Comment: what are the advantages of running grub in a paravirtualized machine instead of booting directly the kernel?

Comment: I don't know. I got this configuration from here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xen#Configuring_a_paravirtualized_.28PV.29_Arch_domU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out that DomU doesn't need a '/boot' partition and that 'raw partition = single partition' (I think). Thus, I need LVM as I still want swap space on my DomU.
Since LVM is not easy, my next question is located at: ...